# Sample Code for a Google Apps Marketplace (GAMv2) in PHP?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-apps-marketplace

I am looking to create an installable Google Apps Marketplace (GAMv2) app in PHP using the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

The [examples in github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples) don't demonstrate how to setup the client object for marketplace apps and how the authentication flow would work. Any help to get me started would be great.

The app will need to access the Drives, Calendars of users and ideally be able to send messages to users that would appear in their Google+ notifications.